# flutter stream_chat version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile-development

Because no versions of shared_preferences match >2.0.5 <3.0.0 and shared_preferences 2.0.5 depends on shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0, shared_preferences ^2.0.5 requires shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0.

And because no versions of shared_preferences_windows match >2.0.0 <3.0.0 and shared_preferences_windows 2.0.0 depends on path_provider_windows ^2.0.0, shared_preferences ^2.0.5 requires path_provider_windows ^2.0.0.

Because stream_chat_flutter >=1.0.0-beta <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on path_provider ^1.6.27 which depends on path_provider_windows ^0.0.4, stream_chat_flutter >=1.0.0-beta <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires path_provider_windows ^0.0.4.

Thus, shared_preferences ^2.0.5 is incompatible with stream_chat_flutter >=1.0.0-beta <2.0.0-nullsafety.0.

So, because jitsist depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.5 and stream_chat_flutter ^1.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because jitsist depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.5 and stream_chat_flutter ^1.0.0, version solving failed.)

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  jitsi_meet: ^0.1.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.0.1

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth:
  pin_code_fields: ^6.0.1
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_core:
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  page_transition: "^1.1.7+6"
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  stream_chat_flutter: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
   intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

name: stream_chat

stream_chat_flutter: ^latest version

change name: .... name you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).